# How can I enable the user to download a file from a server using Django?

Tags: javascript, django

I am using Django 3.1.2 to build a website, and I want the user of my website to be able to download a .zip file created on the backend when they click a button on the webpage.

However, when testing, I found that the download would not start when the button is clicked. No error was thrown either, and I just could not work out where I went wrong.

JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector("#download").onclick = function() {
    // #download is the button I am talking about; it is in reality a div element
    var formData = new FormData();
    for (let i = 2; i < formElementsNumber; i++) {
        let element = formElements[i];
        formData.append(element.name, element.value);
    }
    formData.append("txtFile", formElements[1].files[0]);
    formData.append("token", token);

    // Up to here, everything works fine
    $.ajax({
        url: "/download/",
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,

        // Essential; otherwise will receive an "illegal invocation" error
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        success: function(data) {
            // What should I add here to make the downloading start?
        }
    })
}
```

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('process/', views.process),
    path('download/', views.download)
]
```

views.py:

```py
def download(request):
    // Creates an .zip file
    property_list = ['imageWidth', 'imageHeight', 'fontFamily', 'fontSize', 'rotationDirection', 'rotationAngle', 'foregroundColor', 'backgroundColor', 'token']
    image_info = {}
    for item in property_list:
        image_info[item] = request.POST.get(item)
    image_info['txtFile'] = request.FILES.get('txtFile').read().decode('gbk').split('\r\n')
    // zip_name is the absolute path to the newly created .zip file
    zip_name = w2p.make_zip(image_info, image_info['token'])

    // Everything above works fine; the .zip file is successfully created
    // What modification should I make here to make the downloading start properly
    with open(zip_name, 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f.read())
    response['content_type'] = "application/octet-stream"
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=word2pic.zip'
    return response
```

A thousand thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404

def download(request, path):
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
            response = HttpResponse(fh.read(), content_type="application/filename")
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
            return response
    raise Http404
```